# Return closest value in look up table, and put in list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts like so:

```
my_data = [{'id': 'A', 'density':0.7},
           {'id': 'B', 'density':1.5},
           {'id': 'C', 'density':3.75}]
```

and a Look Up Table (lut) as a list of dicts like so:

```
lut = [{'density': 1.1, 'capacity': 5.19},
       {'density': 2.5, 'capacity': 9.42},
       {'density': 4.3, 'capacity': 16.78}]
```

For each dict in my_data, I want to take 'density' and find the closest corresponding 'density' value in the lut.

I then want to add the corresponding 'capacity' item to that dict.

I've started with a function as so:

```
def function_for_adding_capacity(data, lut):

    my_list_of_dicts = []

    for datum in data:

        for item in lut:

            datum['capacity'] = ...

            my_list_of_dicts.append({
                'id': datum['id'],
                'density': datum['density'],
                'capacity': datum['capacity'],

    return my_list_of_dicts
```

I'm just not sure (1) if I need the second loop, and (2) what to do to find the closest matching density, than returning the corresponding capacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append the capacity to the `my_data` dictionary you can do it with something like

```
def add_capacities(my_data, lut):
    for data in my_data:
        closest = {'density': float('inf'), 'capacity': None}
        for l in lut:
            if abs(l['density'] - data['density']) < abs(closest['density'] - data['density']):
                closest = l
        data['capacity'] = closest['capacity']
```

This starts with a closest match of infinity, and then tests each value in `lut` to see if the density is closer.